# Error: M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: maven

I got this error

```
Error: M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
M2_HOME = "C:/Users/joanet/.m2/repository"
Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of the Maven installation
```

but `C:/Users/joanet/.m2/repository` is a valid directory !

Comment: M2_HOME should address to apache-maven home directory. Example: `C:\apache-maven-3.3.3`

Comment: Remove M2_HOME only add the bin folder of the distribution into your path...not more is neccessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your folder is valid, but this is not the folder you want to point to.

I think it should point actually where the error messages says to you, to your maven installation folder (something like this)

C:\development\maven\apache-maven-3.1.0

You are currently pointing to your local repository, something which is usually configured in the settings.xml of maven (in the conf folder of the previous url route).

Answer (score 1):

Such issue appears also, if you have 2 or more mavens installed. Try to delete old versions to have only latest.

Answer (score 0):

Check the System Variable M2_HOME and PATH values set in different maven installation locations.

Answer (score 0):

If your java version is 8
you can remove "MAVEN_OPTS : -Xms256m - XMX512m" environmental variable and check "mvn -v".
because java 8 does not support for the above config.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I tried to upgrade to new Maven version. 
*Below are the steps you should follow when setting up Maven on Windows*. 
If something is missing, the above error will trigger (most probably the 2nd or 3rd step may be missing for mentioned error).

**Step 1:**

First, download(Apache Maven download link:
https://maven.apache.org) and extract it to `C:\Program Files`
[image]

**Step 2:**

Go to `Environment Variables` and Define below varibles in `System variables`
[image]

> M2_HOME - C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9
>  MAVEN_HOME -
> C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9

**Step 3:**

Make sure to add the `maven bin` file to Path varible in `System variable`
[image]

> C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin

**Step 4:**

Once you are done with configurations, make sure to restart the project.

**Step 5:**

Check whether the Maven is configured successfully using below command

> mvn -version

[image]