# M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory even when it points to maven installation home

Tags: maven

I have set my M2_HOME to

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\apache-maven-3.5.0
```

Contents of above directory

```
09/21/2017  05:13 PM    <DIR>          .
09/21/2017  05:13 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/21/2017  05:13 PM    <DIR>          bin
09/21/2017  05:13 PM    <DIR>          boot
09/21/2017  05:13 PM    <DIR>          conf
09/21/2017  05:13 PM    <DIR>          lib
04/03/2017  08:41 PM            20,934 LICENSE
04/03/2017  08:40 PM               182 NOTICE
04/03/2017  08:36 PM             2,544 README.txt
               3 File(s)         23,660 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  348,568,027,136 bytes free
```

However when I run mvn --version in cmd, I get the following error

```
ERROR: M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
M2_HOME = "C:\Users\abhish\Documents\apache-maven-3.5.0"
Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of the Maven installation
```

I checked a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417447/error-m2-home-is-set-to-an-invalid-directory) on SO. However that didnt help, hence posting this question.

I need this solved to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364181/eclipse-is-not-downloading-plugin-from-central-maven-repo?noredirect=1#comment79688209_46364181) problem.

Comment: Run a `dir` at _C:\Users\abhish\Documents\apache-maven-3.5.0_, what is the content?

Comment: Did you set the M2_HOME with quotes " if yes set it without the quotes

Comment: There are no quotes

Comment: Is this your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034052/maven-m2-home-set-to-an-invalid-directory-windows-7

Comment: @BrunoCésar I have edited the question to show contents of M2_HOME

Comment: How do I check if I have 2 installations on my machine ?

Comment: Looks ok the directory. To check if you have other installation check you environment variables such as `%PATH%`, maybe has other.

Comment: Great there are two actually. I will remove one of them and then try.

Comment: Just put the `C:\Users\abhish\Documents\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin` into your path. Nothing more is needed.Removed M2_HOME....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u are using java 8, please remove "MAVEN_OPTS" from environmental variable and check. because java 8 doesn't support for that config.